# CCLayer scaling and touch implementation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I've made a CCLayer that holds CCSprite and two CCLabelBMFont's. My goal is to create a customized "button" which will scale down when pressed. I've ran into problems with touch and scaling of this layer.

First is the touch, I can't touch the layer bounding box accurately even if I convert the touch like this:

```
CGPoint currentTouchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
```

Touch is handled like this:

```
// Touching shop item?
if(CGRectContainsPoint([self boundingBox], currentTouchLocation)) {
    NSLog(@"Pressing item");
    mShopItemPushed = true;
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Seems like there is no realistic size boundingBox for a CCLayer with it's contents by default so I figure I need to overwrite one based on the CCLayer contents? Any ideas how I can do this correctly?

Second problem is the scaling of this CCLayer based "button". If I get a touch handling to work somehow, scaling the layer down by half causes the scaled layer to move off tens of pixels from the original position. There are no anchors set but still moves the layer quite a bit to the side and up when scaling. How can I prevent this behavior?

Here is some code of the CCLayer based button:

```
+(id) shopItem:(NSString*)fileName : (CGPoint)position : (NSString*)itemName : (int)itemPrice
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithShopItemData:fileName:position:itemName:itemPrice] autorelease];
}

-(id) initWithShopItemData:(NSString*)fileName : (CGPoint)position : (NSString*)itemName : (int)itemPrice
{
    self = [super init];
    [self setPosition:position];

    mShopItemPushed = false;

    mPicture = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:fileName];
    [mPicture setPosition:CGPointMake(position.x - (3.0f * [DeviceSpecific cellSize]), position.y)];
    [self addChild:mPicture z:1];

    // Make price string
    NSString* price = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", itemPrice];

    mItemPrice = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:price fntFile:[DeviceSpecific scoreAndCoinFont]];
    [mItemPrice setScale:0.5f];
    [mItemPrice setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f)];
    [mItemPrice setPosition:CGPointMake(position.x + (3.5f * [DeviceSpecific cellSize]), position.y)];
    [self addChild:mItemPrice z:1];

    mItemName = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:itemName fntFile:[DeviceSpecific scoreAndCoinFont]];
    [mItemName setScale:0.5f];
    [mItemName setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f)];
    [mItemName setPosition:CGPointMake(mPicture.position.x + [DeviceSpecific cellSize], mPicture.position.y)];
    [self addChild:mItemName z:1];

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    return self;
}
```

The [DeviceSpecific cellSize] is just a measuring unit to keep the distances correct on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overwriting the boundingBox -function with a rect based on the outer limits of the items in this layer. Scaling problem remained so I just made another indicator for received touches.